# How to find posts by part of keywords?

Tags: discussion, search

By using full [keywords](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sys.time_zone_info%22), I can find the expected post.

[image]

using [part of keywords](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22time_zone_info%22) can not.

[image]

[without the pair of quotation marks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=time_zone_info), I got unexpected post

[image]

How to find posts by part of keywords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*` as a wildcard: [`*time_zone_info`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=*time_zone_info):

[image]

Not exactly ideal, having to guess where a wildcard might be needed, but better than having no results at all.

The dot is still honoured when using a wildcard, so you can [search for `*.time_zone_info`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=*.time_zone_info) and get 7 hits, because then the uppercase `TIME_ZONE_INFO` result no longer matches.

Answer (score -2):

[image]The "Advanced Search Tips" link you posted in your images will lead you [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) if you click on the "visit our help page" at the bottom of the list.  There, you will find all of the tips for searching with more information including the bit provided by [Martijn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344470/403049):

> - Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk ( * ) anywhere in the word, like encour* or Ex*nge.